# Does vmalloc_to_page returns contiguous physical memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, dma, vmalloc

**Does `vmalloc_to_page` returns contiguous physical memory ?**

I ask because I see that its return value is used for DMA and DMA uses
contiguous memory.

See vmalloc_to_page usage for DMA here:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.70/source/drivers/mtd/nand/onenand/samsung.c#L644

Yet, in `vmalloc_to_page` implementation it does not seem that it creates a contiguous allocation :
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L234

Comment: `vmalloc` doesn't allocate contiguous physical memory. `vmalloc_to_page` returns the page containing an address within a `vmalloc`ed buffer.

Comment: Thanks, so how can it be used for dma usage (see my question) as done in samsung.c ?

Comment: Because it only uses that for single page transfers. A single page is contiguous.

Comment: I understand now. thx